# On Excision property of general probability measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $P$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ , where $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ is the Borel sigma algebra on real line , let $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $\epsilon >0$ , then is it true that there exist a closed set $C$ and an open set $U$ of real line such that $C \subseteq B \subseteq U$ and $P(U \setminus C) < \epsilon$ and that there exist a compact set $K$ such that $K \subseteq B$ and $P(B\setminus K) <\epsilon$ ? I know the excision property for Lebesgue measure , but here the probability measure is arbitrary , also I have no idea about the compact set assertion . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excision property you are looking for is equivalent to the given measure being both inner and outer regular.

Any Borel probability measure on the real line (i.e. the type of probability measure you are referring to), is both inner and outer regular.  See the third bullet point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure#Regular_measures). Note that the real line is locally compact, Hausdorff, and it has a countable basis for its standard topology (i.e. [it is second-countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Number_Space_is_Second-Countable)), thus it satisfies all of the necessary hypotheses.

See for example, Section 7.1 of Dudley's *Real Analysis and Probability* for justification of these claims and more discussion of this topic.